# CentOS 7, cronjob for user does not run script

Tags: centos, cron, privileges

I have CentOS 7.6 on a virtual machine. there some bash script at `/opt` which i need to run them with this user `dbuser`. these scripts write their output in a folder. Using `crontab -e` I put these in `dbuser` crontab so they run every minute:

```
* * * * * /opt/share/scripts/Connections
* * * * * /opt/share/scripts/Memory
* * * * * /opt/share/scripts/Regular
```

when i check the output folder they are not changed every minute. when i run the scripts manually they run without problem and their output is updated correctly.
i checked all of directories and sub-directories to these scripts and they all have the full `x` permission.
in `/var/log/cron` it says that commands are run and there is no error.
i also restarted `crond` service after each change.
i also tried these:

```
 * * * * * /usr/bin/bash /opt/share/scripts/Connections
 * * * * * /usr/bin/sh /opt/share/scripts/Connections
 * * * * * dbuser /opt/share/scripts/Connections
```

and i still get no update in output folders(these commands works fine manually).
finally i added this in root crontab and it is working correctly without error and updates the output files:

```
* * * * * /usr/sbin/runuser -l dbuser -c '/opt/share/scripts/Connections'
```

i can't add every user's crontab to root. i want them to be in their own crontab. why this happen and how i can fix it?

**UPDATE**
the scripts write to a place where user `dbuser` has permission to write. i tested it.
this user is a database user so in the scripts i have the path of database command:
`DB2PATH=/home/$username/sqllib/bin/db2`
should i add this to the path that cronjob use?
no it doesn't send any mail. they produce reports of database status that is for later refer.

Comment: There is no information about the scripts themselves in the question. Do they write to a place where `dbuser` has permission to write, for example? Do they use tools that may not be in the `PATH` used by cronjobs? Does the cron daemon send error messages to the `dbuser` user by mail, which it usually does if a job produces output or errors?

Comment: Do they use environment variables or a custom PATH that's set up in `dbuser`s profile?

Comment: @roaima no they don't.

Comment: @Kusalananda i updated my question.

Comment: @roaima by `crontab -e`. i never restarted `crond` before. here i was just testing if it solve the problem or not.

Comment: `crontab -e` is good. thank you

Comment: You've already confirmed that `cron` says the jobs are running, which is good. Please append `>>/tmp/Connections.log 2>&1` to the first job entry, and follow the pattern for the others. Then check these files for errors.

Comment: @roaima first i added `>>/tmp/Connections.log 2>&1` to crontab commands. the file in /tmp was created but it was empty. then i added `>>/tmp/Connections.log 2>&1` to script, instead of output path, just to  test. file was not created in /tmp although log said it was executed. when i ran `/opt/share/scripts/Connections` manually i got the correct output in /tmp/Connections.log. i dont know why crontab is not able to redirect outputs

Answer (score 1):

You can define the user via `su -` statement. I had the same issue initially with userscripts - this worked for me:

```
* * * * *   root    su - <username> -c "bash <script to run>"
```

Comment: If you are using the system crontab in `/etc/crontab`, change the username in column six from `root` to the user that you want to run the `bash` script as, rather than using `su`.  Doing so would simplify the scheduling.